# Parse Server periodically is getting slow

Tags: azure, parse-server, livequery

- parse-server version 2.7.4 (Azure on a Standard_B4ms)
- mongoDB-server version 3.4.14 (Azure on a separate Standard_B4ms)

I have an iOS & Android app, with LiveQuery (set on the parse-server's VM) that's being used a lot for chatting, where usually there are ± 50 simultaneous users. The thing is, after a few hours of continuous usage, the server's cloud code responses are getting **REALLY** slow! Not just from a specific one... all cloud functions!

I'm using `screen` to run the parse server. So I found that if I restart the parse server (not the vm), the app is getting back to normal.

I also have logs enabled at all times. (just mentioning it in case it could be the issue)

I can't understand why this is happening!
Any ideas?